# How to do click.Command( epsilon=callback() )?

Tags: python, python-click

I have a global function that generates an appendix to my top level help description.
How can I append this text to the top level click command help text?
The appending function takes the current click.Context as an argument in order to be able to iterate over the available commands.

Minimal (non)working example:

```
def helpAppendix(cfx: click.Context)
    return "hello world, {}".format(cfx.invoked_subcommand)
@click.group(epsilon=helpAppendix())
def mycommand(cfx: click.Context):
    """
    This is my command.
    """
    return "Here I am"
```

Running this I would expect:

```
$ mycommand --help
This is my command.
hello world, mycommand
```

Comment: What framework is this? You probably need `@click.group(epsilon=helpAppendix)`, without the `()`

Comment: @tobias_k [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/). I’d call it a library, not a framework.

Comment: Normally, when passing an "action" to handle events, the action has to be `call`-able. In your case, you want to do as tobias_k said and remove the `()` so that you pass the actual function object. You can achieve this another way by using a `lambda` which returns a callable handle to a function. `lambdas` are nice to use when you have arguments that need to be passed to your action function. `@click.group(epsilon=lambda: helpAppendix())` allows you to use `()` which means you can pass arguments, if needed.

Comment: I've tried that with no success: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'epsilon'`. I've also tried `class Help: def __str__(): return "help appendix"`.